# how to convert varchar value to datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, varchar

I have a field `ContractDate` in my table in the format `20/06/2014`. The data type of this field in my table is `varchar(50)`.

I want to convert this `varchar` field into `datetime` format. Any idea ?

i tried this one:

```
decslare @Date nvarchar(10) 
set @Date='12/12/2001' 
select convert(datetime,left(@Date,2)+substring(@Date,4,2)+right(@Date,4))
```

I am getting error...

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: There are almost a dozen links under the "Related" column on the right side of the page, I suggest you review some of those

Comment: i tried those links, but i am getting error... "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
"

Comment: You've tagged c# but talk about `varchar`  Are you trying to do this in sql? or c#?

Comment: i want to do this in sql.. sorry i forgot to mention that..

Comment: There are dozens of google hits for that error.  Which ones have you tried?

Comment: This will come handy - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: i tried this one,   declare @Date nvarchar(10)
set @Date='12/12/2001'
select convert(datetime,left(@Date,2)+substring(@Date,4,2)+right(@Date,4))

Comment: Why are you doing substrings?  `select convert(DateTime,'12/12/2001' )` works just fine.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/35802

Comment: @paqogomez, `'20/06/2014'` will not work. OP's date format is `dd/mm/yyyy` and he is talking about the error that you get if you execute this query with it

Comment: @Typist, Excellent catch.  OP chose an unfortunately ambiguous date in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

`SELECT convert(DATETIME, '20/06/2014', 103)`

From where did I get that `103`? From - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx